# Expandir / Contraer Mat Expansion Panel

Tags: angular, mat-expansion

En mi aplicación de Angular versión 13 estoy utilizando varios mat-expansion-panel lo que estoy intentando es que el panel se expanda o contraiga cuando hago click solo en el icono, lo que no quiero es que tenga esa funcionalidad en el resto del panel solo exclusivamente en el icono, he probado varias soluciones y no lo consigo. Con esta solución lo consigo pero cuando hago click en expandir otro panel el icono previo no cambia de dirección.

```
// EN EL HTML
<mat-accordion displayMode="flat">
  <ng-container *ngFor="panel of paneles">
    <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle [expanded]="estadoPanel[panel.id]">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          {{panel.nombre | uppercase}}
          <button type="button" mat-icon-button (click)="expandirContraerPanel($event, panel.id)">
            <mat-icon>{{estadoPanel[panel.id] ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more'}}</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </ng-container>
</mat-accordion>

// EN EL TS
estadoPanel: {[key: number]: boolean} = {};

expandirContraerPanel(event: MouseEvent, id: number) {
  event.stopPropagation();

  console.log('ID PANEL: ', id)

  if (this.estadoPanel.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    this.estadoPanel[id] = !this.estadoPanel[id];
  } else {
    this.estadoPanel[id] = true;
  }

  this.cdref.detectChanges();
}
```

Con este código tengo además el problema que si hago click en otra parte del panel lo expande o contrae y eso quiero evitarlo también.